# Angular 2. Service return undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular-services

I have 2 services (AuthService & AuthRedirectService)

**AuthService**  uses **Http** service for get simple data `{"status": 4}` from the server and `return response.json().status` <- number

**AuthRediredService** implements **OnActivate** and uses **AuthService** service.  This is the only method **AuthService.GetStatus() : number**, but it returns `undefined`

**AuthService**

```
GetStatus(): number {
    let status: number;
    this.http.get(this.host + "/api/auth/")
    .subscribe((value: Response) => {
      status = value.json().status;
      console.log(value.json().status); // write real number 4
    });
    return status; // 4
  }
```

**AuthRedirectService**

```
  canActivate() : boolean
  {
    console.log(this.auth.GetStatus()); // undefined  !!!!!!!!
    if(this.auth.GetStatus() == StatusCode.Logined)
    {
      // redirect code
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: `http.get` is asynchronous, you will have already returned out of `GetStatus()` before it resolves.

Comment: You can check out Gunter's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function for inspiration and a deeper understanding of async canActivate() implementations.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple Javascript asynchronous problem and it's nothing to do with Angular2.

In javascript , when you call a async method , like a http call that might resolve after 10mintues , you can't expect to have the result right away :

Let's say :

```
   myAsyncFunction(){
       let theResult;  // First: this line fired
       callAHttpServiceThatTakes1Minute() // Second: we called the function that returns the result in 1 mutine
       .then((res)=>{
          theResult = res; // Forth :  will be available after 1 minute 
       });

       console.log(theResult); // Third : This is undefined because number Forth hasn't finished yet.
   }
```

To fix your problem though , your route should be something like this :

```
 { path : 'home' , component : HomePageComponent , resolve : { user : GetStatusResolver } } ,
```

And then :

```
@Injectable()
export class GetStatusResolver implements Resolve {
    constructor ( private auth : AuthService ) {
    }

    resolve ( route : ActivatedRouteSnapshot , state : RouterStateSnapshot ) : Observable<User> {
        return  this.auth.GetStatus() ;
    }
}
```