# auth guard not waits observable

Tags: angular

I have auth guard service

```
 constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    if(this._auth.isLoggedIn()){
      return true;
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

and that's my isloggedin method

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
  return this._session.sessionId.length > 0;
}
```

and login

```
login(user: User): any {
 return this._http.post(this.authUrl, user)
   .subscribe(x => {
     this._session.sessionId = x.sessionId;
     this._session.name = x.username;
   });
}
```

my problem is that after login it first check's `isloggedin` and I think it's because of `subscribe` (login method waits response from server)

so I added `asObservable.first()` in `isLoggedIn`

```
isLoggedIn(): boolean {
  return (this._session.sessionId.length > 0).asObservable().first();
}
```

but it logs in console that

> Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type 'boolean'.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Where is `login()` being called from?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer after user will click to login button. it takes parameters from form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `subscribe()` then the call returns a `Subscription` not an `Observable`

It's not clear from your question what `login()` is supposed to do exactly but because you `return` the result of the `_http.post()` call I suspect you actually want to return an `Observable`. For this you need to change `subscribe` to `map` (`map` needs to be imported):

```ts
login(user: User): any {
 return this._http.post(this.authUrl, user)
   .map(x => {
     this._session.sessionId = x.sessionId;
     this._session.name = x.username;
   });
}
```

**update**

```ts
constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private _router: Router) { }

loggedIn = new Subject();

login(user: User): any {
 return this._http.post(this.authUrl, user)
   .map(x => {
     this._session.sessionId = x.sessionId;
     this._session.name = x.username;
     this.loggedIn.next(true);
   });
}

canActivate() {
  return loggedIn.map(loggedIn => {
    if(this._auth.isLoggedIn()){
      return true;
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm posting data to the server and it returns me `sessionId` and `username` that's why I'm subscribing to that

Comment: Then `return` seems redundant.

Comment: anyway with or without return it first goes to isloggedin and then to login. When I click to login button second time then returns isloggedin true (but it's second call to server and `sessionId` is not the same)

Comment: I updated my answer. If some of the methods are within the service (for example `_auth` - wasn't exactly sure from the code in your question), then just prefix the call with `this._auth` and move the subject to the service)

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: can you help me in one more thing? this code works and guard waits subscribtion to finish but after that auth guard not working

Comment: Perhaps you need `first()` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function/38425489#38425489

Comment: I added that and it navigates for the first time but then when I want to navigate using `routerLink` it isn't going inside return statement

Comment: Hard to tell. Perhaps something like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10014

Comment: what's difference between subscription and observable? when I write map instead of subscribe i'm not getting values

Comment: A `Subscription` allows you to cancel the subscription, but doesn't allow you to apply any operators. If you pass a `Subscription` the receiver can't subscribe and has no way of getting values from. If the receiver needs to subscribe, you need to pass an `Observable` instead, this is also what the router expects to receive from the guard.