# How to call an async method in canActivate with angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs

I am trying to implement a canActivate guard for an admin route in Angular 4.2.4.

Based off this stack question here: [canActivate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function), I think I'm doing everything correctly. But alas, I can't seem to get things to work.

**Here is the module guard:**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _store: Store<AppState>,
              private router: Router,
              private czauth: CzauthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.czauth.verifyAdminUser().first();
  }
};
```

**Here is my czauth service:**

```
  getToken():Observable<firebase.User>{
    return this.af.idToken;
  }

  verifyUserRole(token){
      this.token = token;
      console.log(token);// Log out "PromiseObservable {_isScalar: false, promise: D, scheduler: undefined}"
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.get(environment.api+'/verifyadminuser', options).map((response)=>{return response.json()});
  }


  verifyAdminUser():Observable<boolean>{
    return this.getToken()
      .map((user)=>{return Observable.fromPromise(user.getIdToken())})
      .map((token)=>{return this.verifyUserRole(token)})
      .do((response)=>{console.log(response)})// Always returns "Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}"
      .switchMap((response:any)=>{ return response.status === 200 ? Observable.of(true) : Observable.of(false)});
  }
```

I can never get the response from my http async call. I always get what looks to be a cold observable in the console. It's as if the router never subscribes to my observable? I would like to return a boolean based off what my http response is. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I am calling the `verifyAdminUser` method from my guard. The service is a sinlgeton on the root module. The guard is protecting access to a lazy-loaded module.

Below I have included where I am using the guard in the routing.

Routing Module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren : './landing/landing.module#LandingModule'},
  {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren : './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule', canActivate: [ AuthGuard ]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The trouble is when the user tries to navigate to the dashboard module, canActivate always returns false because the response in my switchMap operator is undefined.

**EDIT 2:**

I refactored and simplified the following two methods in my code, and now everything works just fine. Now, I'm trying to understand why. Here are the adjusted to methods:

```
  verifyUserRole(){
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this.http.get(environment.api+'/verifyadminuser', options).map((response)=>{return response});
  }


  verifyAdminUser():Observable<boolean>{
    return this.getToken()
      .map((user)=>{
        user.getIdToken().then((token)=>this.token = token);
        return user;
      })
      .map(()=>{return this.verifyUserRole})
      .switchMap((response:any)=>{ return response ? Observable.of(true) : Observable.of(false)});
  }
```

**Solution:**

Thanks to @BeetleJuice excellent answer below, I was able to create a derivative solution.
Here are the two methods I refactored:

```
  verifyUserRole(token){
    this.token = token;
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(environment.api+'/verifyadminuser', options).map((response)=>{return response});
  }


  verifyAdminUser():Observable<boolean>{
    return this.getToken()
      .switchMap((user)=>{return Observable.fromPromise(user.getIdToken())})
      .switchMap((token)=>{return this.verifyUserRole(token)})
      .map((response:any)=>{ return response.status === 200 ? true : false});
  }
```

Comment: having a hard time getting what you're asking. (1)How are the two code excerpts you posted related? (2) which function exactly fails to behave as you'd like?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I have edited my question, does this help explain it better?

Comment: What's your thinking behind using `mergeMap` at the end of `verifyAdminUser`?

Comment: If I use a map, I get a Type error "Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>' because I need to merge the Observable.of with the current stream....but I think you're right. Going with just a map at the end and returning a boolean is cleaner.

Comment: For those who are looking for angular6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363905/536388

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pay attention to this line, taken from `verifyUserRole`

```
console.log(token);// Log out "PromiseObservable...
```

So `token` is an observable, but you're treating it as a string on the very next line so the server will probably reject that request

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token})
```

You're misusing the `.map` operator in `verifyAdminUser()`.  `map` should only be used with synchronous functions. For example:

```
// this works if user.id is a property available immediately
return this.getToken().map(user => user.id)
```

`map` should not be used with asynchronous functions. For instance:

```
// this fails since the return value is an Observable that will resolve later
return this.getToken().map(user => Observable.fromPromise(...))
```

`map` returns immediately. As a result, what gets passed down the chain is not the token itself as you expected, but rather an Observable that will produce the token in the future.  That's why`console.log(token)` gave you "PromiseObservable".  What you need is an operator that will wait for the observable in it to produce, then pass the emitted value to the next operator.  Use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

```
//this will work; switchMap waits for Obervable.fromPromise 
// to emit before continuing
return this.getToken().switchMap(user => Observable.fromPromise(...))
```

So basically, replace `map` with `switchMap` in lines 3 and 4 of `verifyAdminUser`. You can also simplify the last line of `verifyAdminUser` by doing the reverse: change

```
.switchMap((response:any)=>{ return response.status === 200 ? Observable.of(true) : Observable.of(false)})
```

with

```
// no need for switchMap because response.status is available immediately
.map(res => res.status===200? true: false)
```

Also, you are using `canActivate` incorrectly. This is meant to guard against the activation of a component. To guard against the loading of a lazy-loaded module, use canLoad guard. So I would either replace `canActivate` with `canLoad` (if I want to protect the entire module), or move the `canActivate` guard to the specific route that has the `component:` property within `DashboardRoutingModule` (I'm guessing at the name)

[See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-guard-guarding-unauthorized-loading-of-feature-modules)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! This is awesome. I'm going to re-read your answer and experiment more with this. Clearly I have a lot more to learn with rxjs.

Comment: You're welcome @calbear47 . If it helps you, upvote the answer. If it fixes the problem you reported, select it.