# Async authguard in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I would like to provide a server-side authentication before I give access to a specific route in angular.

I have a AuthGuard which implements CanActivate and a service AuthService.
The authService already has a `private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);`
 which views subscribe to in order to know if the user is logged in or not. I don't really know if my approach is wrong, but it does not seem to work.

This is what I have in auth.guard.ts:

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated().map((isLoggedIn) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    })
}
```

and this is auth.service.ts:

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private loggedIn: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) {

    }

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
    }

    isAuthenticated() : Observable<boolean> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

        return this.http.get('/user', {headers: headers}).map(
            response => {
                if (response['username']) {
                    this.loggedIn.next(true);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: what's the error ? any feedback ?

Comment: Well at this point the error is just a 401, which I guess I could handle, but I feel like I've tried multiple things without success and I'd just like to know if I'm on the right track... should I even have canActivate return a Observable, or a boolean? Should isAuthenticated provide a Observable too ? What about the loggedIn variable, is it required? Do I need isLoggedIn *and* isAuthenticated, isn't it the same ? etc... I'm a bit lost, really, and I found some code snippets but couldn't make them work...

Answer (score 4):

Here is approach for RXJS6, added a variable `_isAuthenticated` in authentication service to request the server state just when the flag is disabled. I hope that helps others.

Ensure `canActivate` returns a plain boolean or an observable. The route handler will subscribe to the given observable and reacts to first boolean value coming from the value stream.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/';
import { map, finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private dataService: DataService,
              private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(): any {
    const isAuthenticated = this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated();

    // All good
    if ( isAuthenticated ) {
      return true;

    // Hmm, let's verify the user first
    } else {
      return this.authenticationService.isSessionAlive()
        .pipe(
          map(res => {

            // No valid session; let's move to the login page
            if ( res === false ) {
              this.router.navigate(['/login'], { replaceUrl: true });
            }

            return res;
          })
        );
    }
  }

}
```

auth.service.ts (I'm using rxjs 6)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService } from '@app/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  private _isAuthenticated = false;

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this._isAuthenticated;
  }

  isSessionAlive(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.dataService.SessionIsAlive()
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this._isAuthenticated = true;
          observer.next(res.success); // your server response
        }, (err) => {
          this._isAuthenticated = false;
          observer.next(false);
          // observer.error(err); // won't work here you need to use next
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the `_isAuthenticated` boolean will always return false in the auth guard before the request to the server has finished and is able to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You might do bit of changes as follows,

Your service,

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  public isUserLoggedIn: boolean;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private auth: AuthService) {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
  }

  public loginService(data): void {
    this.auth.isAuthentication(data)
    .subscribe((response) => {
      if (response) {
        this.isUserLoggedIn = true;             
      }else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }

 public getUserLoggedIn() {
   return this.isUserLoggedIn;
}
```

and then,

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private login: LoginService) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.login.getUserLoggedIn();
  }
}
```

Comment: On other components, I used to have   this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn; and then *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async". What would be the equivalent now ?

Comment: And what's    this.auth.isAuthentication ?

Comment: that is where you authenticated by passing your credentials on the service side

Comment: So you mean that I should have my http.get there, instead of your     this.auth.isAuthentication(data), right? And what is loginService(data) ? It looks like a second constructor, who calls it ? I tried your version, and in the chrome dev tools, it seems that '/user' is never called...

Comment: Also, if I don't use async in the loggedIn variable, and the logger disconnects, my html component won't be notified and the ngIf won't change, no ? I need to be notified on various parts of the application when the user login status changes