# How to handle asynchronous data when creating Angular route guard

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, rxjs

I am trying to implement an auth guard in an Angular app which uses Firebase version 9 as backend. My goal is to set canActivate true when user has a document in Firestore, false otherwise. However I am having difficulties caused by asynchronous data when I try to get current authenticated user and user's documents from Firebase.
**Auth guard does not wait for User service to fetch current user and it's data. It returns false before User service even gets the current user in it's constructor.**
I have tried using Promises but not succeeded, I have checked other questions and tried to use Observables but was not able to apply them to my case. Here is my minimal code:

User service:

```
  export class UserService {

      firebaseApp: any;
      db: FirebaseFirestore;
      auth: Auth;
      user: any;

      constructor() {
        
        this.firebaseApp = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
        this.db = getFirestore(this.firebaseApp);
        this.auth = getAuth(this.firebaseApp);
        onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, user => {
          this.user = user;
        })
      }

      
    async isNewUser(uid: string): Promise<boolean>{
        return new Promise<boolean>( async resolve => { 
          const docRef = doc(this.db, "users", uid);
          const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
          if (docSnap.exists()) {
            console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
            resolve(false);
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
            resolve(true);
          }
        })
    
      }


   isLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {    

    return new Promise<boolean>(async resolve => {
      if(this.user == null){
        resolve(false);
      }else{
        await this.isNewUser(this.user.uid).then(res => {
          resolve(res);
        })
      }
    })
   
  }
}
```

Auth guard:

```
  constructor(private userService: UserService){}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot):  Promise<boolean> {

      return new Promise<boolean>(resolve => {
        this.userService.isLoggedIn().then(res=> {
          resolve(res);
        });
       });

  }
```

Also, what is the best practice here? How can I guarantee that user is not null, or data is fetched before calling any other function?

Comment: Could be the way you applied the route guard to the routes. Returning a promise or observable from a canActivate call works just fine.

Comment: This might help, if you would go for an `Observable`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425461/angular2-canactivate-calling-async-function

Comment: Actually the problem is canActivate cannot return correct Promise or Observable, because I cannot get data before canActivate returns something.
I checked that answer, but I don't want to import any Auth related things to Auth guard. This type of solution is the last resort for me.

Comment: Did you try to directly return the service instead of returning yet another new Promise? so simply return this.userService.isLoggedIn() in canActivate?

Comment: Have yo tried this: ... return  await new Promise(... ?

Comment: Unfortunately none if those solutions worked, because user is still null when isLoggedIn() or canActivate() returns. What I need is to wait till I got response from Firebase and then return the result.